# Undefined references to sse2 asm

Tags: c++, assembly, android-ndk, x86-64, sse

We are using the libjpeg_turbo and livpx C++ libraries in our Android ndk application ( using Android studio 3.1 building for 64bit x86) but are getting link errors specifically related to sse2  functions. These libraries depend on a couple of static libraries that contain these asm functions which we have included in the build. For example below

```
  ./../third_party/libjpeg_turbo/simd/jsimd_x86_64.c:73: error: undefined reference to 'jconst_rgb_ycc_convert_sse2'
```

The missing jconst_rgb_ycc_convert_sse2 function is present in the libsid_asm.a static library which we have included in the build

using nm on this lib we can see it is present

```
 0000000000000000 R jconst_ycc_rgb_convert_sse2
 0000000000000a90 T jsimd_ycc_extbgr_convert_sse2
 0000000000000e30 T jsimd_ycc_extbgrx_convert_sse2
 00000000000003a0 T jsimd_ycc_extrgb_convert_sse2
 0000000000000740 T jsimd_ycc_extrgbx_convert_sse2
 0000000000001180 T jsimd_ycc_extxbgr_convert_sse2
 00000000000014d0 T jsimd_ycc_extxrgb_convert_sse2
```

So we think we have done all the relevant checks but can't understand why we are getting these errors. Anyone know what else we should be looking for

Comment: Verify the files are listed in the correct order. Some linkers depend on that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks it turns out that's what it was. If you answe rthe question I'll accept it